# java - how to break from a forEach method using lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, foreach, java-8

Basically I have a list and its elements will be processed one by one until some condition is met. If that condition is met for any element, it should return `true` otherwise `false`. The method looks like:

```
public boolean method(List<Integer> data) {
    data.forEach(item -> {
        if (some condition is met) {
            return true; //  Getting Unexpected return value here
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Is there a way to break out of this forEach loop right after the condition is met instead of looping through all the elements?

Comment: That looks like [`Stream#anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)? Or how does that not work for you?

Comment: No, but you can use a for loop

Comment: @UnholySheep That's the correct way to go. You should provide an answer with that suggestion ...

Comment: I understand, that I can use a for loop or `Stream#anyMatch` for this particular example. But I'm wondering if there is a way to break out of forEach loop.

Comment: "But I'm wondering if there is a way to break out of forEach loop." => No, there isn't. And why should it? There are (better) ways to do that. A `forEach` simply does what it says: It executes an action _for each_ element, not less.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose there is, but it's very ugly - throw an Exception

Comment: @Eugene Yes, and that's why I even won't tell someone (especially a beginner) that there is such a possibility. Besides that, it's not only ugly, it uses a mechanism not designed for that purpose.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
data.stream().anyMatch(item -> {condition})
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. What if `condition` is not an expression, but a set of computations?